# For Var In Loop - Can I omit a variable from it?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
function Vanguard(name,grade,skill,power,shield,critical, type, nation, clan, race, imageURL){
    this.name = name;
    this.grade = grade;
    this.skill = skill;
    this.power = power;
    this.shield = shield;
    this.critical = critical;
    this.type = type;
    this.nation = nation;
    this.clan = clan;
    this.race = race;
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
};

var database = {};
database['asura kaiser'] = new Vanguard("Asura Kaiser", 3, "Twin Drive!!", 11000, 0, 1, "Normal Unit", "Star Gate", "Nova Grappler", "Battleroid", "http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120428001646/cardfight/images/thumb/a/a6/VGE_BT01-008EN.jpg/300px-VGE_BT01-008EN.jpg");
database['king of knights, alfred'] = new Vanguard("King of Knights, Alfred", 3, "Twin Drive!!", 10000, 0, 1, "Normal Unit", "United Sanctuary", "Royal Paladin", "Human", "http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121009013434/cardfight/images/thumb/9/95/BT01-001EN_RRR.jpg/300px-BT01-001EN_RRR.jpg");
database['dragonic overlord'] = new Vanguard("Dragonic Overlord", 3, "Twin Drive!!", 11000, 0, 1, "Normal Unit", "Dragon Sanctuary", "Kagerou", "Dragon", "");
database['ceo amaterasu'] = new Vanguard("CEO Amaterasu", 3, "Twin Drive", 10000, 0, 1, "Normal Unit", "United Sanctuary", "Oracle Think Tank", "Human", "");
database['alfred - early'] = new Vanguard("Alfred - Early", 3, "Twin Drive!!", 10000, 0, 1, "Normal Unit", "United Sanctuary", "Royal Paladin", "Human", "");

function printVanguard(p, name){
      for (var p in database[name]){
         document.getElementById('output').innerHTML +=('<b>' + p.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + p.slice(1) + '</b>: ' + database[name][p] + '<br />');
      }
};
```

In my printVanguard function, is there a way I can use the for var in loop but print out everything EXCEPT the variable imageURL? Right now the code works but I'm looking to modify it so that the imageURL variable in the Vanguard object does NOT print out.

(This is not my full code, only what's relevant. If you need my full code let me know.)

Comment: Brilliant! I had tried that before, but omitted the quotes ' around imageURL and that's why it wouldn't compile. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: You are already making Vanguard a class, so you could move the printing functionality to a function of that class.

Comment: Don't do `.innerHTML += ...` in a loop *(or at all really)*. It does ugly things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it's not a variable, but a property. You can prevent outputting it by adding a simple condition:

```
   for (var p in database[name])
       if (p !== "imageURL")
           document.getElementById('output').innerHTML +=('<b>' + p.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + p.slice(1) + '</b>: ' + database[name][p] + '<br />');
```

If you are adding prototype methods to your `Vanguard`s, you also might consider using [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to omit inherited properties as well. However, for using this code in production you hopefully won't enumerate just the whole object, but either explicitly pick properties or use a nested object which contains only the data.

Or you can skip the property with the loop by making it non-enumerable. However, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) is a ES 5 feature and will not work in older browsers:

```
this.imageURL = imageURL;
Object.defineProperty(this, "imageURL", {enumerable: false});
```

Comment: Note that "older browsers" includes IE8

Comment: Thanks so much!! Exactly what my problem was - I was treating it as a variable and not a property. I had tried the if statement before but forgot the quotes ' around imageURL.

Comment: I'd prefer `!==` over `!=` and it might be wise to include a `.hasOwnProperty` check, in case a prototype chain is set up.

Comment: `p` actually *is* a variable containing the property name

Comment: @Bergi sure, but `imageURL` is _not_ a variable.